# Permanently Turn off wifi hotspot option

Tags: wireless, 22.04, hot-spot

How to  disable turning on wifi hotspot in  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: Is ap-utils installed?

Comment: Yes in my organization also many are misusing this , & it makes more load to our network